# Why are parts of my greasepencil animation rendering black?

Tags: rendering, animation, grease-pencil

I'm making a hybrid animation (3d + greasepencil) stickfigure fight in blender. When I render, some parts render with the vertex colours that they're supposed to have. In others,the stickfigures are appearing fully black in the render.

I've had this happen in other parts of the animation (on different project files). I've looked at other forum posts that had the same issue, but I couldn't find a universal solution.

I've tried resetting the vertex colours, changing the composition nodes, changing the world lighting settings, changing the material colours to match the desired vertex colour, appending the work onto another file, but nothing worked.

Specs: 6 core AMD Ryzen 5500U Processors, 2.1 GHz processing speed, Integrated AMD Radeon graphics, 12 GB RAM

[image]

[image: Example 1]
[image: Example 2]